# Laravel 4 development server crashing without notice

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am developing an application in Laravel 4 using the built-in development server with a SQLite database. After a recent merge from another user in the project repository, the server will crash after certain requests.

I believe I have narrowed it down to a call of `Sentry` - when it is used on a request the server will crash out and the command line will exit.

```
$ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000
Dwight at Dwights-MacBook-Pro.local  ~/Sites/tmtbl on master*
$
```

As you can see, there are no error notices.

I've run `composer update` and ensured that `Sentry` is still installed correctly. I'm not sure whether this issue is `Sentry` specific or something else is going on. Is there something I am missing here that is causing the server to crash?

Comment: Can you give more details what exactly do you mean by "crash" ?

Comment: The server renders out the page up until the point that `Sentry::check()` is called in the view. Then the server effectively exits on the command line, and goes to a new prompt. Because it crashes at that point, none of the assets like stylesheets or images are able to be loaded into the page either.

Comment: Sounds like a trivial issue. Any problems running on a real server?

Comment: Attempting to deploy now but worked when testing through MAMP. Would still like to resolve this as it is my development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Chrome? If yes, go to the console and if you have an error, is it the same as: [Failed to load resource when using Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430264/failed-to-load-resource-when-using-auth)? Because I have the same problem with the php 5.4 server

Comment: Using Chrome, but I have no issue when testing with the Laravel Auth library. I don't get any error on the console, the server just exits.

Comment: I mean in the chrome console

Comment: Nothing in the Chrome console apart from failing to load the assets because the server had exited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Chrome browser to see the errors in the console.

---

**Process**

First run: `php artisan config:cache`

Second run: `php artisan serve`

Finally: go to your localhost and inspect your page, and then go to the console in the upper tab, you might be able to see the error.

Image of console:

[image: See the image of console here]

Moreover, you can try:

```
composer dump-autoload
```