# Failed to load resource when using Auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

## The problem

If I use the class Auth in a route/view/controller what so ever, I get the following error in chrome/firefox etc: `Failed to load resource   URL_TO_CURRENT_PAGE:LAST_LINE_NUMBER`

The Html is correct, if I copy the code and paste it into a .html file and open it via the webserver I get no errors.

## My code

http://paste.laravel.com/zpp

is this a bug or is it my fault?

Comment: Does it actually says `URL_TO_CURRENT_PAGE:LAST_LINE_NUMBER` or is it you that replaced those for privacy ?

Comment: its replaced because its on every site das uses the Auth class. In my case it is localhost:8000/login:89

Comment: can you paste the full error?

Comment: that was the full error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the problem is the library entrust. If I dont use it, everything works as intended.