# Artisan development server quits after every request

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel/Composer and MVC frameworks in general. I've been going through some very good tutorials but in my development environment, each time I run

```
php artisan serve
```

in terminal and then make an HTTP request, the development server process is killed. The log doesn't record any errors at the time the request is made or the process is killed. [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424964/laravel-4-development-server-crashing-without-notice) seems similar and is the only other thing I could seem to find, but for me the issue is happening on a fresh install and I'm not invoking the Sentry call anywhere (it even occurs when i request a simple static html or image file). Is there something I need to do to keep the server running after a request is made?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: How do you send your HTTP request? (If it's with a browser, which one?)

Comment: Hi Philippe, I'm currently using Chrome to make requests. I've tried Safari and FF with the same result.